# Folder Actions and screensaver issue

Tags: macos, usb, screensaver

I have a Folder Action Setup in /Volumes that detects when a USB is insert.
this it its structure

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    delay 1 -- ALLOW MULTIPLES TO BE ADDED BEFORE PROCESSING - OPTIONAL

    try
        set theFileContents to read "/Volumes/My_USB/Network.txt"
    on error errstr
        set theFileContents to false
    end try

    if theFileContents is false then
        say "wrong USB"
    else
        say "right USB"
    end if  
end adding folder items to
```

It works fine unless the when screensaver (with password prompt) kicks in.

How can I have it working also when locked screensaver in ON?

Thanks!

Comment: update: it looks like no /Volume is mounted while screensaver asks for password.
Is there any solution to bypass this?

Comment: update2: I thought it could be a SIP problem, but it looks like it has nothing to do with SIP, since it I disabled it on the computer, and it still has the same problem.
Basically when screensaver (with password prompt) is running no /Volumes are mounted...

Any way to prevent this?